# Serving static mp4 files with Express Js

Tags: node.js, video, express

I want to get access to the raw video files on my node js server and for some reason I can't see the *.mp4 videos.

I do this to serve the static files:

```
app.use("/videos", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'videos')));
```

I tried to access `*.jpg` or `*.png` from that folder and it worked. When I try to access and mp4 file on OS X I just get and empty video player and on Windows I get the `Cannot GET <videoPath>`.

Am I missing something here? Do I have to add the mime type somewhere?

Comment: "`Cannot GET <videoPath>`" What is the value of `<videoPath>`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 'videos' directory is in your 'public' folder on your server, most likely the same place as your index.html, then the following should work:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'videos')));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. The only difference is that I mapped that folder to the `/videos` route

Comment: Well this definitely works - can you share more of your code and your logs? Maybe the issue is somewhere relayed rather than this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to put `/` in your video path.

Here's the working code on my video folder:

```js
app.use("/video", express.static(__dirname + "/video"))
```

You can access it in the browser with this:

```
http://localhost:port/videos/filename.filetype
```

Or:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port/videos/filename.filetype
```